# ivy-hydra: error upon C-o

Tags: prelude, ivy, hydra

While trying to figure out [another problem](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38803/prelude-ivy-how-to-select-and-open-multiple-files). I was advised to use the ivy-hydra package.

By default, it appears that ivy-hydra is NOT included with prelude-ivy. So I did a `package-install` <kbd>ret</kbd> `ivy-hydra`.

That seemed to install it, but then when I do a <kbd>C-o</kbd> I get a message saying

```
symbol's value as variable is void: ivy-preferred-re-builders
```

I have no idea how to move forward to resolve this. I guess it is something about regular expression builders? How does one correctly install ivy-hydra when working from a prelude-ivy install?

Comment: `ivy-hydra` is an official part of the [`swiper`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/) project but, just like `swiper` and `counsel`, is not installed along with `ivy` by default. This way, users can choose precisely which functionality they want installed. You can suggest the inclusion of `ivy-hydra` in the `prelude-ivy` module on [Prelude's issue tracker](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude). The error is likely due to stale packages; just try reinstalling `ivy`.

Comment: I had the same issue and managed to resolve it by installing the latest `ivy` package.